# Django: How to change "view on site" url of admin button

Tags: python, django

In my app I'm using the django-photologue (3rd-part app) and in its default configuration, the "View on site" admin button point to its template.

I've read that the "View on site" button use get_absolute_url() model function to implement its behavior.

I need to change the url behind "View on site" button.
Do I need to override get_absolute_url() or edit other things??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't change files of third-party apps if you can avoid it, because you'll essentially need to maintain a fork of the app. Instead of overriding `get_absolute_url`, you can override the `object-tools` block in the admin template. Something like this:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block object-tools %}
{% if change %}{% if not is_popup %}
  <ul class="object-tools">
    {% block object-tools-items %}
    <li>
        {% url opts|admin_urlname:'history' original.pk|admin_urlquote as history_url %}
        <a href="{% add_preserved_filters history_url %}" class="historylink">{% trans "History" %}</a>
    </li>
    {% if has_absolute_url %}<li><a href="{% url 'your-custom-view-here' original.pk %}" class="viewsitelink">{% trans "View on site" %}</a></li>{% endif%}
    {% endblock %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Save this as `templates/admin/photologue/<modelnamehere>/change_form.html` (change `<modelnamehere>` to the model you want to customize)

In a future version of Django (1.7 I guess), you will be able to [override the method `view_on_site`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L252) to do the same thing.

Comment: I guess there is an easier solution now. See [latest docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.site_url).

Answer (score 0):

Overriding get_absolute_URL() is proposed in the Django docs so it should be good to go.

See: [Other model instance methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url)

Comment: Ahh I missed that detail. The object-tools block is a good choice it his case. Good luck :-)